# Can I use a "Film" to wrap something?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am looking at the [Merriam Webster definition of "film"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/film)

In its point 3. it says "*b (1) : a thin flexible transparent sheet (as of plastic) used especially as a wrapping"*

How common is this usage?  I am a bit reluctant to use this word, and instead prefer using "wrapping"

EDIT: I am using the word to meaning packing small objects such as candies on a series of packages of several materials (can be plastic, or paper, etc)

Comment: If you mean using *film* as a verb, no.

Answer (score 4):

"Film" normally refers only to the specific type of wrapping known (at least in the US) by the most common brand name, "Saran Wrap".

[image]

Otherwise things like candies are said to be *individually wrapped in plastic (or paper)*.

Store-bought products that are covered in a thin plastic film are said to be *shrink-wrapped*.

[image]

Comment: In the UK the common name for 'Saran Wrap' style products is 'Cling film'.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the context.

I think this usage of the word *film* is both familiar and understandable, although it's generally seen in more of a technical context than heard in everyday conversation.

For example, I don't think I would ever say either of these to a friend, family member, or co-worker:

- Please cover that macaroni with some film and put it in the refrigerator.
- I need some plastic film to put over this avocado.

However, I would not be surprised to read sentences like these in a scientific journal, or in some company's promotional or training materials:

- All monitor screens are covered with a protective film before being moved to the warehouse.
- A thin sheet of plastic film is placed across the opening, which is then heated to create a vacuum fit.